# Channels terminate prematurely

Tags: go, channel

I am prototyping a series of go routines for a pipeline that each perform a transformation.  The routines are terminating before all the data has passed through.

I have checked Donavan and Kernighan book and Googled for solutions.

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    a1 := []string{"apple", "apricot"}

    chan1 := make(chan string)
    chan2 := make(chan string)
    chan3 := make(chan string)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    go Pipe1(chan2, chan1, &wg)
    go Pipe2(chan3, chan2, &wg)
    go Pipe3(chan3, &wg)

    func (data []string) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for _, s := range data {
            wg.Add(1)
            chan1 <- s
        }
        go func() {
            wg.Wait()
            close(chan1)
        }()
    }(a1)
}

func Pipe1(out chan<- string, in <-chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for s := range in {
        wg.Add(1)
        out <- s + "s are"
    }
}
func Pipe2(out chan<- string, in <-chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for s := range in {
        wg.Add(1)
        out <- s + " good for you"
    }
}
func Pipe3(in <-chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for s := range in {
        wg.Add(1)
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}
```

My expected output is:

```
apples are good for you
apricots are good for you
```

The results of running main are inconsistent.  Sometimes I get both lines.  Sometimes I just get the apples.  Sometimes nothing is output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Adrian already pointed out, your WaitGroup.Add and WaitGroup.Done calls are mismatched. However, in cases like this the "I am done" signal is typically given by closing the output channel. WaitGroups are only necessary if work is shared between several goroutines (i.e. several goroutines consume the same channel), which isn't the case here.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a1 := []string{"apple", "apricot"}

    chan1 := make(chan string)
    chan2 := make(chan string)
    chan3 := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        for _, s := range a1 {
            chan1 <- s
        }

        close(chan1)
    }()

    go Pipe1(chan2, chan1)
    go Pipe2(chan3, chan2)

    // This range loop terminates when chan3 is closed, which Pipe2 does after
    // chan2 is closed, which Pipe1 does after chan1 is closed, which the
    // anonymous goroutine above does after it sent all values.
    for s := range chan3 {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}

func Pipe1(out chan<- string, in <-chan string) {
    for s := range in {
        out <- s + "s are"
    }

    close(out) // let caller know that we're done
}

func Pipe2(out chan<- string, in <-chan string) {
    for s := range in {
        out <- s + " good for you"
    }

    close(out) // let caller know that we're done
}
```

Try it on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/d2J4APjs_lL

Comment: That addresses my needs.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `wg.Wait` in a goroutine, so `main` is allowed to return (and therefore your program exits) before the other routines have finished. This would cause the behavior your see, but taking out of a goroutine alone isn't enough.

You're also misusing the `WaitGroup` in general; your `Add` and `Done` calls don't relate to one another, and you don't have as many `Done`s as you have `Add`s, so the `WaitGroup` will never finish. If you're calling `Add` in a loop, then every loop iteration must also result in a `Done` call; as you have it now, you `defer wg.Done()` before each of your loops, then call `Add` inside the loop, resulting in one `Done` and many `Add`s. This code would need to be significantly revised to work as intended.

Comment: Your answer was useful.  Thank you!  Working code would have been even better!